# In Java is there any difference between Hibernate Session, JSP/Servlet Session and Session of transaction management

Tags: java, hibernate, spring

Is there any differences between hibernate session and the session which you use while programming with servlet jsp and the session which we use in transaction management in spring

Comment: It's Java and JSP, not JAVA and Jsp. JSP is an abbreviation, Java isn't!

Comment: Hey Patrick thanks for your valueable information

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, they have no relation to each other at all. They mean different things in different contexts, and need to be managed differently according to what they mean and how they should be used.

Comment: Can u give me more information about it or any url from where i got more information regarding it.                                         thanks

Comment: @dubodh: No, because your question is too vague. The things you're talking about are all different, so you need to ask questions about specifics.